List items in Beamer frame not disappearing and occupying space
I'm facing an issue with displaying a long list of items in a Beamer frame. I have a frame with a large number of list items, and I want to gradually hide the earlier items as I progress through the presentation. However, even though the earlier items are not visible, they still occupy vertical space, which is preventing the later items from being displayed.
Here is the code I am using:
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-4> one
    \item<2-5> two
    \item<3-6> three
    \item<4-7> four
    \item<5-8> five
    \item<6-9> six
    \item<7-10> seven
    \item<8-11> eight
    \item<9-12> nine
    \item<10-13> ten
    \item<11-14> eleven
    \item<12-15> twelve
    \item<13-16> thirteen
    \item<14-17> fourteen
    \item<15-18> fifteen
    \item<16-19> sixteen
    \item<17-20> seventeen
    \item<18-21> eighteen
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

Is there a way to make the earlier list items not only invisible but also not occupy any space, so that the subsequent items can be displayed without being pushed out of the frame?
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.
Thank you for your help.

Please always add a compilable test document to your questions!

To remove the items from other overlays, you could use only@...:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<only@1-4> one
    \item<only@2-5> two
    \item<only@3-6> three
    \item<only@4-7> four
    \item<only@5-8> five
    \item<only@6-9> six
    \item<only@7-10> seven
    \item<only@8-11> eight
    \item<only@9-12> nine
    \item<only@10-13> ten
    \item<only@11-14> eleven
    \item<only@12-15> twelve
    \item<only@13-16> thirteen
    \item<only@14-17> fourteen
    \item<only@15-18> fifteen
    \item<only@16-19> sixteen
    \item<only@17-20> seventeen
    \item<only@18-21> eighteen
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}

This can also be done automatically:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<only@+-.(3)>]
    \item one
    \item two
    \item three
    \item four
    \item five
    \item six
    \item seven
    \item eight
    \item nine
    \item ten
    \item eleven
    \item twelve
    \item thirteen
    \item fourteen
    \item fifteen
    \item sixteen
    \item seventeen
    \item eighteen
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}


